# really new to meteor, and trying to deploy website to galaxy, but its not working

Tags: meteor

So I just got into meteor like a month ago, and I just finished my first website after about 2 weeks. Its a social media website kinda like twitter. I also downloaded accounts-ui and accounts-password packages, and I implemented them in the website pretty loosely. But heres the thing, I wanna deploy the website to galaxy using the subdomain .meteorapp.com,  and it just doesn't seem to work. I keep getting the same error in the logs which is:  "Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment". I looked it up, and I just dont know what to do. from what I read online you need to make a settings.json file, then add this code:

```
"galaxy.meteor.com": {
"env": {
"ROOT_URL": "http://blueslipgang.meteorapp.com/",
"DEPLOY_HOSTNAME":"galaxy.meteor.com"
"MONGO_URL":"mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor"
 }
}
```

so thats what I did, and i added this file to the client file, the server file, and even inside no file. I just cant seem to get the website to deploy. I really wanna deploy this website so me and my friend's can use it, but its just not deploying.
so what am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to fix it. Any help would be really, really appreciated, I worked pretty hard to make this app, and it would really suck if I cant even deploy it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Galaxy doesn't provide a MongoDB service, so you will need to sign up for a MongoDB account (Atlas has a free tier) and use that. Setting the MONGO_URL to localhost/127.0.0.1 will throw an error on launch.

Also, to use the `settings.json` when deploying, you will need to make sure you have the `--settings` flag set in your deploy command:

```
DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy [hostname] --settings settings.json
```

Also have a read through the [official galaxy guide](https://galaxy-guide.meteor.com/deploy-quickstart.html)

If you have ongoing problems, I suggest posting on the [Meteor forums](https://forums.meteor.com/) and the community can help step by step with each issue you run into

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, and I dont want to disturb you too much, but I have a couple of questions, do I need to put the settings.json in a specific file, like client or server, or should I just leave it out and just put it in my main file. And for the mongoDB, were do i create the account, and once i do, what do I do. I just create the account and thats it.

Comment: You just need to be able to point to the `settings.json` file when running deploy as the argument after `--settings`. I usually leave it in the root of my project. You can sign up for MongoDB Atlas at https://www.mongodb.com/

Comment: Im sorry to disturb you again, but what do I do once I create a mongodb account, like were do i find the MONGO_URL?

Comment: When you log in, you should see your cluster in the dashboard. Click the connect button, followed by "connect your application", pick the Node driver, with the lastest version and it will give you a connection string that you use for your `MONGO_URL`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, really really appreciate it! Im still having some issues with my settings.json file, but im just gonna ask the meteor community you linked me to! again, your help really ment a lot.

Comment: I thought there wouldd be some back and forth to get this working, which is why I suggested it. Save you waiting for me to see a comment on SO. I'm a mod on the forums, so I'll see you there :)